# Satis - How to set name in generated packagist packages.json

Tags: php, composer-php, satis, packagist

Here are the docs:

- http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/handling-private-packages-with-satis.md

Here is my config.json file

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
    },
    "name": "Local Packagist",
    "homepage": "http://blah/packagist",
    "repositories": [
        { "type": "vcs", "url": "http://blahsvn/myProject/my-bundle" }
    ],
    "require-all": true
}
```

After running the satis build command I get this in my composer.json file ( SEE HERE ):

```
{
    "require": {
        "myProject/my-bundle": "2.1.*"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "myProject/my-bundle", <-- HERE
                "version": "2.1.1",
                ...
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

When I generate the packages.json file I see this ( SEE HERE ):

```
{
    "packages": {
        "myProject/not-my-bundle-name": {
            "2.1.1": {
                "name": "myProject/not-my-bundle-name", <-- HERE
                "version": "2.1.1",
                ...
```

How do I get the two to match so I can pull with composer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run satis build, you get a packages.json which contains all the info it found in the repositories you configured. So if `http://blahsvn/myProject/my-bundle` has a composer.json file in trunk/, it will define the name of the bundle. If the name does not match what you want, make sure you change it in trunk.

Then what you add in your project's composer.json is a repository of type "composer", and with the url pointing to your satis repo. Do *not* redefine the packages, otherwise you lose the whole point of satis. It should look like this:

```
{
    "require": {
        "myProject/my-bundle": "2.1.*"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "http://blah/packagist"
        }
    ]
}
```

That is assuming `http://blah/packagist/packages.json` is the stuff dumped by satis.

Note: You don't have to define any autoloading in the satis config.json.

Comment: Thanks, I think that's the problem. I have it named something else in the composer.json file in trunk. Just for my understanding composer executes all the composer.json files for each project, correct?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "executes all the composer.json files for each project".